# Making Extension method Generic

Tags: c#-3.0

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/c-automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern) there's a very interesting way of updating UI threads using a static extension method.

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Control c, Action<Control> action)
{
    if(c.InvokeRequired)
    {
        c.Invoke(() => action(c));
    }
    else
    {
        action(c);
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is to make a generic version, so I'm not constrained by a control. This would allow me to do the following for example (because I'm no longer constrained to just being a Control)

```
this.progressBar1.InvokeIfRequired(pb => pb.Value = e.Progress);
```

I've tried the following:

```
  public static void InvokeIfRequired<T>(this T c, Action<T> action) where T : Control
    {
        if (c.InvokeRequired)
        {
            c.Invoke(() => action(c));
        }
        else
        {
            action(c);
        }
    }
```

But I get the following error that I'm not sure how to fix. Anyone any suggestions?

> Error 5   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: In fact... looking a bit closer, I seem to get the error on the first code example too... although I'm actually compiling for .NET 4.0 at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace :

```
c.Invoke(() => action(c));
```

with :

```
c.Invoke(action, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known error with lambdas and anonymous methods:

[Convert this delegate to an anonymous method or lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515/help-convert-this-delegate-to-an-anonymous-method-or-lambda)

Your code just needs a cast to compile:

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired<T>(this T c, Action<T> action) where T : Control
{
    if (c.InvokeRequired)
    {
        c.Invoke((Action<T>)((control) => action(control)));
    }
    else
    {
        action(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: won't work either. You need to provide the action's argument to the `Invoke` method

Answer (score 0):

Try this slight varient:

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired<T>(this T c, Action<T> action) where T : Control
{
    if (c.InvokeRequired)
    {
        c.Invoke((Action<T>)(() => action(c)));
    }
    else
    {
        action(c);
    }
}
```

You need to cast it as a Delegate type.  Kinda stupid I know.  I can't really give you a good reason why a lambda expression isn't implicitly assignable as a delegate.

Comment: It won't work, because `action` takes a parameter, and you're not passing it to `Invoke`

Comment: good point.  edited to account for that.  for some reason I was thinking Invoke passed in the current control, which is totally not the case.